# How to get a Google Cloud Datastore entity in Android without App Engine?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-endpoints

Is it possible? I have been searching in the Google Cloud documentation and all around the internet, but found **nothing**. I need to read some values from the Datastore in an Android app made with Android Studio. I tried the Cloud Datastore library but **the Gradle build crashes**, and tried to use it with App Engine unsuccessfully.
I want to use this database or a similar database, but **not Firebase** because it would exceed the limits for sure, so you can suggest other databases.

Answer (score 0):

You can always query the Datastore for entities using the [REST API](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/rest/)'s [runQuery](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects/runQuery) method.

If you were willing to build an App Engine backend, you could definitely use [Cloud Endpoints](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/) to allow your android app to use it and the [Datastore. The Cloud Datastore Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/libraries) do not work on Android but they will work on App Engine (and in other environments).